# Найти максимальное среднее значение

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужно найти, какой артист(artname) имеет максимальную среднюю цену(average cdprice).Есть таблицы

Artist:
[image: artist]

CD:
[image: cd]

Пробовал написать:

```
SELECT artname 
FROM cd, artist 
GROUP BY artname 
HAVING (SUM(cdPrice)/COUNT(cd.artid)) >= ALL(SELECT (SUM(cdprice)/COUNT(cd.artid)) FROM cd,artist ar WHERE ar.artid=cd.artid GROUP BY ar.artname);
```

Но не получилось.

Comment: Начать нужно с условия связи между таблицами, т.е. вы имеете декартово произведение.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант:

Найти артиста с максимальной средней ценой пластинки

```
SELECT TOP (1) artid FROM CD
GROUP BY (artid)
ORDER BY avg(cdprice) DESC
```

Соответственно найти имя артиста

```
SELECT artname FROM Artist WHERE artid = 
(
SELECT artid FROM CD
GROUP BY (artid)
ORDER BY avg(cdprice) DESC
LIMIT 1
)
```

**UPD**. Поправил под PostgreSQL

Comment: Такой функции нету:   ERROR:  function top(integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT artname FROM artist WHERE artid= (SELECT TOP(1) artid...
                                                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @RoarRaizZer согласен, ее заменит limit 1

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Самый универсальный вариант:

```
select a.artname
from   (select cd.artid, avg(cd.cdprice) as avg_cdprice
        from cd
        group by cd.artid
        ) c
    join artist a on c.artid = a.artid
where c.avg_price = (select max(avg_price)
                     from (select cd.artid, avg(cd.cdprice) as avg_cdprice
                            from cd
                            group by cd.artid
                            ) cc
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам смог разобраться:

```
SELECT artName FROM Artist, CD WHERE Artist.artID = CD.artID
GROUP BY artName HAVING AVG(cdPrice) >= ALL(SELECT AVG(cdPrice) FROM CD GROUP BY cdGenre);
```